# If elseif Condition

Tags: php

I want to display a series of outputs by using while loop and if condition, but here the if condition only works and the other conditions like elseif and else are not working. Please help me.

This is my code

```
    if($expid=='3606' OR '3660' OR '3661' OR '3662' OR '3684' OR '3685')
    { 
        $exp='1';
    }
    elseif($expid=='3607' OR '3608' OR '3612' OR '3620' OR '3621' OR '3622' OR '3623' OR '3624' OR '3625' OR '3626' OR '3636' OR '3646' OR '3647' OR '3648' OR '3649' OR '3650' OR '3651' OR '3652' OR '3653' OR '3654' OR '3655' OR '3656' OR '3657' OR '3658' OR '3659' OR '3605')
    {
        $exp='2';
    }
    elseif($expid=='3609' OR '3610' OR '3611' OR '3613' OR '3614' OR '3615' OR '3616' OR '3617' OR '3618'  OR '3619' OR '3627' OR '3628' OR '3629' OR '3630' OR '3631' OR '3632' OR '3633' OR '3634' OR '3635' OR '3637' OR '3638' OR '3639' OR '3640' OR '3641' OR '3642' OR '3643' OR '3645')
    {
        $exp='3';
    }
    elseif($expid=='3666' OR '3667' OR '3668' OR '3669' OR '3670' OR '3671' OR '3672' OR '3673' OR '3674' OR '3675' OR '3676' OR '3677' OR '3678' OR '3679' OR '3680' OR '3681' OR '3682' OR '3683')
    {
        $exp='4';
    }
    else{
        $exp='5';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `if('3660')` is true :) You need something like `if($expid=='3606' OR $expid=='3660' etc..)`

Comment: Why do you not try with in_array function it can help you to write short code. write you condition value in array in match in_array.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are doing it wrong. Simply use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) instead, to avoid confusion.

```
if(in_array($expid,array('3606','3660','3661','3662','3684','3685')))
{
```

Comment: You are write, this is the best way to get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

`$expid=='3606' OR '3660' OR '3661' OR '3662' OR '3684' OR '3685'` will always be `true` because `'3660'` is evaluated as true.

But you may need to reconsider your logic and not do hard coding this numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($expid=='3606' || $expid=='3660' || $expid=='3661' || $expid=='3662' || $expid=='3684' || $expid=='3685')
    { 
        $exp='1';
    }
```

like this you have evaluate each expresion to return true or false

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this. Your OR statement is just a string. '3660' will always be true. you have to do $expid==3660, and the same goes for all of your other OR clauses.

`if($expid=='3606' OR '$expid==3660' OR $expid=='3661' OR $expid=='3662' OR '$expid==3684' OR $expid=='3685')`